# How to change Shell Tabbar height

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer, xamarin.forms.shell

My Problem:
I use Shell with bottom `Tabbar` and I simply want to change it height on Android and maybe on iOS.

My Search Results:
I know that the `Tabbar` is an Android/iOS build in feature with solid specified height.

There seems to be a way to achieve that using a "Custom-Renderer". All projects I have found with this approach don't work with my visual studio (>100 Errors or simply does nothing).

I find it hard to believe that i need >100 rows of code to "only" adjust a height. Could someone provide a working solution to change the Shell Tabbar (bottom tabs) height ?

#### Edit

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfourtounately you need to create a custom renderer on each platform project:

#### Android

`MyShellRenderer` class

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(App.AppShell), typeof(App.Droid.MyShellRenderer))]

namespace App.Droid
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
        {
            return new MyBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(this, shellItem);
        }
    }
}
```

`MyBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker` class

```
class MyBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker : ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
    {
        public MyBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext, ShellItem shellItem) : base(shellContext, shellItem)
        {
        }
        public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
        {
            bottomView.LayoutParameters.Height = 400;
            base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);
        }
    }
```

#### Edit:

iOS part credit goes to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/169894/how-to-change-shell-height-of-flyout-items-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

#### iOS

`MyShellRenderer` class

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(App.AppShell), typeof(App.iOS.MyShellRenderer))]

namespace App.iOS
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {

        protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new MyCreateTabBarAppearanceTracker();
        }
    }
}
```

`CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker` class

```
class CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker : ShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
    {
    
        public override void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            UITabBar tabBar = controller.TabBar;
            int tabBarHeight = 100;

            if (tabBar.Frame.Height != tabBarHeight)
            {
                tabBar.Frame = new CGRect(tabBar.Frame.X, tabBar.Frame.Y + (tabBar.Frame.Height - tabBarHeight), tabBar.Frame.Width, tabBarHeight); 
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Extras

You were probably missing some namespaces that would explains the abnormal big number of errors.

> could not be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Usually people don't include namespaces (`using` statements) in answers because most of the time namespaces are obvious and are handled easily by visual studio intellisense.

Just put or hover the cursor on the red underlined statement and a small tooltip appears

[image]

Then click on "Show potential fix" or one of the keyboard shortcuts, select the appropriate fix (usually the first one of the suggested list), in this case intelisense will add the required namespace automatically.

Comment: For iOS you need to do something similar

Comment: "BottomNavigationView" is underlined red do you know why? it gives an error: namespace not foudn

Comment: you must have this using statement `using Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation;` usually intelisense handle this.

Comment: OMFG THANK YOU!! i dont know why every code expample excludes the using directives......

Comment: because most of the time namespaces are obvious and are handled by visual studio intlisense, when clicking "ctrl+." or "ctrl+enter" while cursor is on an undefined statement intelisense will suggest and  add the required namespace automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Every Code example i have found has excluded the using directives. in my case i needed those following 3 which i wasnt able to find. Thanks to the answer of @Cfun the code above work with adding:

```
using Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
```

Comment: FYI: When there is a red underlined name, and you hover over it, you should get an icon with options to correct it. One of those options is to add the needed using directive. This is why people often don't bother with "using"s in a small code snippet.